# How to expose nginx on public Ip using NodePort service in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubectl

I'm executing `kubectl create -f nginx.yaml` which creates the pods successfully. But the PODS aren't exposed on Public IP of my instance. Following is the YAML used be me with service type as nodeport:

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    name: nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      nodePort: 30080
      name: http
    - port: 443
      nodePort: 30443
      name: https
  selector:
    name: nginx
```

What could be in-correct in my approach or above YAML file to expose the pod on deployment to the public IP?

PS: Firewall and ACLs are open to internet on all TCP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jeel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48860487/1924666) is right. Your Service selector is mismatch with Pod labels.

If you fix that like what Jeel already added in this answer

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    name: nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      nodePort: 30080
      name: http
  selector:
    name: nginx
```

Your Service will be exposed in Node IP address. Because your Service Type is NodePort.

If your Node IP is, lets say, `35.226.16.207`, you can connect to your Pod using this IP and NodePort

```
$ curl 35.226.16.207:30080
```

In this case, your node must have a public IP. Otherwise, you can't access

**Second option**, you can create LoadBalancer Type Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    name: nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: http
  selector:
    name: nginx
```

This will provide you a public IP.

For more details, [check this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/)

Answer (score 6):

The endpoint was not getting added. On debugging I found the label between deployment and Service has a mismatch. Hence changed the label type from "app" to "name" and it worked.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    name: nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      nodePort: 30080
      name: http
  selector:
    name: nginx
```

Comment: yes , that must be in the top thanks